# Vue Router doesn't seem to like function calls

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

In my `router/index.js`, I am trying to lazy-load the route. If I hard-code the string it is working but if I use a function (as shown) call to get that file path as a string value, it shows me an error in the console - `Error: Cannot find module '../views/Login/Login.vue'`. I'm using Vue 2.6.11 and Vue-router 3.5.1.

Where am I going wrong?

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

// const filePath = (filename, foldername) => '../views/' + foldername + "/" + filename + '.vue'


const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Login',

        // THIS WORKS
        component: () => import('../views/Login/Login.vue')

        // THIS DOES NOT, EVEN THOUGH IT IS GETTING THE EXACT SAME VALUE
        // component: () => import(filePath('Login', 'Login'))
    },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes
})

export default router
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to lazy-load a route, it has to be statically analyzable, like this:

```
component: () => import('../views/Login/Login.vue')
```

In your other attempt:

```
component: () => import(filePath('Login', 'Login'))
```

The import is not statically analyzable by the build tool (probably webpack). The build tool is in charge of identifying which code is being used and which code is not (that's called tree-shaking).
As it can't resolve the actual import (it would be possible only at runtime since `filePath` could return anything), it considers that the vue file is never referred to, and should be removed from the build.

If your actual build tool is webpack, you have to follow webpack's instructions described here: https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import which states that is possible to have dynamic imports when they have a statically analyzable pattern (e.g: template literals)

Answer (score 0):

You should let webpack to know in which root folder it will load the component files, so you should move `../views/` to the import parameter instead of the returned value of your function :

```
const filePath = (filename, foldername) => foldername + "/" + filename + '.vue'


const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Login',
        component: () => import('.../views/'+filePath('Login', 'Login'))
    },
]
```

Comment: Okay, but why does it do that?